# How to covert string data like 2016-4-10 00:00:00 to timestamp?

Tags: android, date, datetime

I want convert data like **2016-4-10 00:00:00** to timestamp.

I use this code (I send this date as argument to this method):

```
public static long parseUTimeAndGiveTimestamp(String time) {
    if (time != null && !time.equals("")) {    
        long longTime = 0;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date;
       try {
           time += ".000";
           date = sdf.parse(time);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return longTime;
       }
       longTime = date.getTime();
       return longTime / 1000;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But I get **1460235600** value and if I convert it to date again I get:
**Sat, 09 Apr 2016 21:00:00**

(before **10**.04 - after **09**.04)

So you can help me?

Comment: why you added extra .SSS in simple date format. remove and and try. Also I think you need to decrees value of of Month because its starting for 0-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with your code. There is some issue with the timezones. Your SimpleDateFormat will be using your local timezone. You probable might be getting the timestamp for your locale and while converting it back to the date, you are checking in GMT timezone. To test this just add

`sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

before parsing the date.

So basically you are not using the same timezones to convert date to timestamp and while converting timestamp to zone.

Answer (score 1):

try to use one `M` to parse single-digit month format. It also handles two-digits correctly...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd kk:mm:ss.SSS");
```